# Allow external users to login using custom SAML app in Google Admin

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I have created a custom SAML application in the Google Admin panel for my workspace account to allow users to login via SSO to an application using their Google Workspace credentials. Currently only users of my organisation can login to this application. I want to make it so that users of an external organisation can also login to this application using their Google Workspace credentials using SSO. How do I do this?

Tried:
I have created a Google Group and all users who should have access to this application (both internal and external organisation users) and turned on access to this Google Group in the access settings of the custom SAML app.

Expected:
Both internal and external users should be able to login to the application.

Result:
Only internal users are able to login to the application using their credentials. When an external user tries to login they are shown 403 - app_not_configured_for_user error